# Web page doesn't behave as though checkboxes are checked after manipulating in the console

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, checkbox, console.log

Excuse my limited ability to be able to frame the question. I need to check 100 boxes to apply an accounting rule to 100 bank entries (in FreeAgent). In the console in Google Chrome I have typed the following, which succesfully checks the first box in the list. (Once it works I will put it in a loop so it checks all of them but I'm not at that point yet.)

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('FormElement-checkbox');
x[1].firstElementChild.checked = true;
```

When I try to continue with the procedure, the web page doesn't "realise" that the boxes have been checked. I can only get it to work if I physically click the checkboxes individually on the page - the fact they appear checked doesn't seem to matter to the page. So there is obviously something I am missing.

I can succesfully enter text into boxes and select items in drop downs. I have tried inspecting the checkbox element and seeing what happens when it is checked by clicking on it, but I can't see any difference in the HTML. I have explored a lot of the attributes in the javascript for that object when typing

```
x;
```

which is how I found the .firstElementChild.checked = true in the first place.

I don't know whether it is something specific to the page itself or whether in general I don't have enough experience to be able to tackle all data entry situations yet. I have tried searching for answers on this forum and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('FormElement-checkbox')
x[0].checked = true;
```

or use the `click()` method on checkbox element.

Part of HTML document might be helpful.

Comment: Yes I tried that version and I also did try the click() method as well but no luck. Here is the HTML where the checkbox is located:

`<td class="Table-cell--fitToContents">`

`<div class="FormElement-checkbox">`

`<input type="checkbox">`

`<span></span>`

`</div>`

`</td>`

Comment: I think you made mistake with selecting checkbox element. You should set true on deeper nested element because checkbox have element inside it.
`x[0][0].checked = true; `

EDIT: Sorry. I see you know that.

Answer (score 0):

This happens most likely because of some JS/CSS trickery - the elements are listening to `click` event rather than change in HTML property. Try raising .click event

```
var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("FormElement-checkbox")

for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++){
    cbs[i].click()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('FormElement-checkbox');
var result = "document.getElementsByClassName('FormElement-checkbox')";
  for (var i=0, len=x.length|0; i<len; i=i+1|0) {
  result += "\n  " + x[i].textContent;
   }
```

You can also try using:

```
document.querySelector(".FormElement-checkbox")
```

to get the first element with the class_name (or)

```
document.querySelectorAll(".FormElement-checkbox")
```

to get a list of elements with the class_name

You can find everything about Document.getElementsByClassName() here at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)